# How to install wget on Mac OS

Tags: macos, homebrew, wget

I am trying to install wget on my Mac but when ever I try to install it it says

```
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "wget".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps
```

I have tried to uninstall Homebrew and then re install it but it still doesn't work. Please Help (Also this is my first post so if you have any comments on it please tell me)

Comment: Try doing `brew update` first and then attempt to do `brew install wget`. Can you comment on whether you see better results after doing that?

Comment: I just did it... it said up to date and the same error popped up :(